# Delay on calculation OnChange event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two numbers in DECIMALS. The problem is that it takes around 2-3 sencods, this is a problem since the inputs are time, and the user can fire the event really quick and it seems to crash somehow.
Could this be coming from not round the decimals? I just need 2 digits after coma.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="date" name="" id="">
<input type="time" step="300" name="" id="startTime" onkeydown="return false" />
<input type="time" step="300" name="" id="endTime" onkeydown="return false" />
<input type="text" id="totalHours">
</body>


<script>

document.querySelector("#startTime").onchange = function (e) {
}

document.querySelector("#endTime").onchange = function (e) {
    timeDiff();
}

function timeDiff() {
    var start = document.querySelector("#startTime").value;
    var end = document.querySelector("#endTime").value;


    var startSplit = start.split(":");
    var startHsToMinutes = startSplit[0] * 60;
    var startTotalMinutes = parseInt(startSplit[1]) + startHsToMinutes;

    var endSplit = end.split(":");
    var endHsToMinutes = (endSplit[0] * 60);
    var endTotalMinutes = parseInt(endSplit[1]) + endHsToMinutes;

    var totalHours = endTotalMinutes - startTotalMinutes;
    document.querySelector("#totalHours").value = totalHours / 60;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event instead of the `change` event:

```
document.querySelector("#endTime").oninput = function (e) {
    timeDiff();
}
```

The MDN documentation on the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event explains the difference:

> The `change` event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the `input` event, the `change` event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

The keyword is *committed*. The moment at which a value is *committed* can be implementation dependent. For a standard text `input` element, this happens when the element loses focus. But in this particular case (a `time` type `input`) Chrome will trigger the `change` event after the use of the up/down arrows, but the timing may vary. Sometimes it is almost immediate, sometimes there is a delay.

The `input` event is more suitable for tracking each and every change, independent on how the user made it -- via keyboard, context menu, drag-'n-drop, buttons that are integrated inside the widget...), and it triggers immediately.

Comment: Amazing solution. Thank you very much. Could you please explain me the difference between these two?

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer.